# table1 join table2 on table1.varchar is equal to prefix+table2.numeric_id+suffix

Tags: mysql

I am writing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM notes inner join item_source 
 on notes.item_ids=CONCAT(CONCAT(',', cast(item_source.id as varchar(10))), ',')
```

`item_source.id` is the primary key (numeric, auto_increment) of table `item_source`.
`notes.item_ids` is a `varchar` field of table notes.

I want `item_source.id`=`18` to match `notes.item_ids`=`',18,'`.

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(10))), ',')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to covert it to char data type then u can get result

SELECT * FROM notes inner join item_source 
 on notes.item_ids=CONCAT(CONCAT(',', cast(item_source.id as char(10))), ',')

Comment: Solved indeed. Thank you